# Backbone this is undefined

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

I've been having trouble with backbone and asked several people for help, but no luck so far.

I create a new collection like this

```
let eventsCollection = new BandEvents({artist: 'Muse'});
```

In the collection, I do this

```
const BandEvents = Collection.extend({
    model: Artist,
    url: 'http://api.bandsintown.com/artists/' + this.artist + '/events.json?api_version=2.0&app_id=SomeID',

});
```

When I run this code, I get the following error in the browser console

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'artist' of undefined
```

So the this in `+ this.artist +` is undefined. I have no idea what I'm doing wrong.

Answer (score 2):

*this* is undefined because the collection is not instantiated when you set url here. I recommend using the url function if you need to have that be dynamic: http://backbonejs.org/#Collection-url

Answer (score 0):

This is how I solved it

I changed

```
let eventsCollection = new BandEvents({artist: 'Muse'});
```

to

```
let eventsCollection = new BandEvents($('#artist-input').val());
```

(I need to get the artist name from an input field)

And changed

```
const BandEvents = Collection.extend({
    model: Artist,
    url: 'http://api.bandsintown.com/artists/' + this.artist + '/events.json?api_version=2.0&app_id=SomeID',

});
```

to

```
const BandEvents = Collection.extend({
    model: Artist,
    initialize: function (artist) {
        this.url = `http://api.bandsintown.com/artists/${artist}/events.json?api_version=2.0&app_id=ShowEvents`;
    }
});
```

For this I use ES6's [Template Literals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals)